# How to prevent root device to bypass certificate pinning in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rooted-device, certificate-pinning

I am developing a project that require the Android app can prevent bypassing certificate pinning/trust a fake cert when doing network calling even in a rooted devices.

So far I can make it when the device is not rooted. I just need to prevent some bypassing method like using JustTrustMe in Xposed framework.

I am using retrofit and okHttp during network calling.

I have tried the using CertPinner in okHttp and its version is 3.10.0
and also tried to follow the code in android developer https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#java

here is the sample code i have tried and copied from google

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
// (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

And the cert pinning sample code

```
String hostname = "publicobject.com";
CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
    .add(hostname, "sha256/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=")
    .build();
OkHttpClient client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
    .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("https://" + hostname)
    .build();
client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Both are the simplest code but none of it working

I would like to make it at least prevent some bypassing method like using JustTrustMe in Xposed framework/some easy automated bypassing method.

May i know if it is possible to do it or not, I have also tried some libs like 
https://github.com/moxie0/AndroidPinning

suggested by JustTrustMe

https://github.com/Fuzion24/JustTrustMe

Comment: You kinda have to assume trust execution environment, and on a rooted device the trust is gone. What is the threat you're trying to protect against with cert pinning?

Comment: i am trying to prevent mitm attack

Comment: If a successful MITM requires also compromising the device where the code is running, you already have mitigation to MITM threats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, load CAs from an InputStream would not work for all rooted devices with bypassing module enabled. It still works for normal device

The only way I could prevent it is to use public key cert pinning with proguard at the same time, hope this only help some ppl encounter the same problems.

Comment: could you please explain how you did it and is it working fine for now.?